# getinitiallink in react native firebase returns same value with mulitple deeplink urls

Tags: firebase

I have implemented deeplink using Firebase react native. App works fine but getinitial link is always returning first url value clicked.

I have multiple deeplink url.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example or relevant code reporducing the problem and list any steps that you have taken to solve the issue so far.

Comment: i think i have to use onlink to get update. i place this in componentDidMount     const unsubscribe =   firebase.dynamicLinks().onLink(url => {
      alert('1')
    })  this never get called

Comment: await firebase.dynamicLinks().getInitialLink().then((initialLink) => {
      if(initialLink) {
        alert(initialLink)
      } else {
        alert('else')
      }
    }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));